# equation representing 2 straight lines

Tags: analytic-geometry, factoring, coordinate-systems

Let us assume this equation is given to us we have to factorize it
    $$12x^2 +7xy-10y^2+13x+45y-3=0$$
By solving we get that this represents two straight lines.
But how to factorize it? Is there a way which we can factorize all such equations which represents two straight lines or it require some special technique ?

Comment: At the intersection point, it is the product of two factors which are both zero, so the $x$ and $y$ derivatives are both zero.

Comment: can u plz elaborate

Comment: See [Degenerate Conics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic).

Comment: If I have not made a typing error, [Wolfram Alpha thinks this is a hyperbola](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+12*x^2+%2B7*xy-10*y^2%2B13*x%2B45*y-3%3D0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my mind.  First factorize $12x^2+7xy-10y^2$ as the product of two factors $(ax+by)(cx+dy)$.  It is just like factoring an ordinary quadratic.

Then bring in $e$ and $f$ like this: $(3x-2y+e)(4x+5y+f)$  The *linear terms* are
$e(4x+5y)+f(3x-2y)=13x+45y$  Collect the coefficients of $x$, so $4e+3f=13$, and also an equation for $y$.

You now have two equations in $e$ and $f$ to be satisfied at the same time.  If you can solve them, you are done.

As a check, $ef$ should equal -3.  If they don't, it was a hyperbola, not a pair of lines.

Comment: That last sentence would seem to imply the original equation would always be a hyperbola or a pair of lines. There are other branch points, though - when $a,b,c,d$ are not real, for example.

Comment: Yes, if you can't factor the original quadratic, because the discriminant is negative, then you have an ellipse or a circle or a single point or an empty set.  I guess Joseph's link will tell you about that.  And about when the discriminant is zero.

Comment: The case where $ad-bc=0$ is the parabola case if there is no solution for $e,f$, and two parallel lines if there are $e,f$.

Comment: But @Michael you can factor this for a hyperbola right? Then wouldn't a hyperbola and that those two lines have the same equation?

Answer (score 0):

The general version of the quadratic equation of which you give a special example will represent a conic or a degenerate conic section. There is a long history of using "invariants" associated with the coefficients of this general equation to determine what one has. One discussion of this can be found here: http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node28.html but you can also look up information about "discriminants." Scroll down for some treatment of this on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section